# not defined string in Label because of entry, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
if checked_a==1:
dulj_a=math.sqrt(stranica_1_duljina **2 - stranica_2_duljina**2)                                    #riješiti str_a
str_dulj_a= str(dulj_a)

ispis_dulj_a=Label(window, text= dulj_a , font=("Arial", 30,"bold"), bg="lightblue")
ispis_dulj_a.place(x=1250,y=800)



def ispis_a():
    ispis_a_text=Label(window, text="Duljina stranice a iznosi" + str_dulj_a  , font=("Arial", 30,"bold"), bg="lightblue")
    ispis_a_text.place(x=1200,y=800)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\Python-programi\Pitagora v2.py", line 159, in ispis_a
    ispis_a_text=Label(window, text="Duljina stranice a iznosi" + str_dulj_a  , font=("Arial", 30,"bold"), bg="lightblue")
NameError: name 'str_dulj_a' is not defined
```

Comment: I've fixed most of the formatting but I don't know what belongs in the `if` block

Comment: Hi there, could you point out your problem a little more? My current guess is that `str_dulj_a` **is not defined** when `checked_a` != 1

Comment: Yes, checked_a is Checkbutton and if it is on then you need to enter numbers and when program calculate those numbers there is button that needs to make label, but calculation needs to me in text of the label

Comment: @LovroPriselec Mind re writing the code? because we don't know what exactly in `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `checked_a` is a button and will equal to `1` if it's **on**. What if the button is **off** you can also define your `str_dulj_a` before calling `ispis_a` some elsewhere in your line of code

like

```
if checked_a==1:
   dulj_a=math.sqrt(stranica_1_duljina **2 - stranica_2_duljina**2)                                    
   #riješiti str_a
   str_dulj_a= str(dulj_a)
else:
   str_dulj_a = "some string"
```

or initialise it at the beginning

```
str_dulj_a = "init string"

if checked_a==1:
   dulj_a = math.sqrt(stranica_1_duljina **2 - stranica_2_duljina**2)
   str_dulj_a = str(dulj_a)

ispis_dulj_a=Label(window, text= dulj_a , font=("Arial", 30,"bold"), bg="lightblue")
ispis_dulj_a.place(x=1250,y=800)

def ispis_a():
    # Now you have a defined string of `str_dulj_a`
    ispis_a_text=Label(window, text="Duljina stranice a iznosi" + str_dulj_a  , font=("Arial", 30,"bold"), bg="lightblue")
    ispis_a_text.place(x=1200,y=800)
```